# Change style of tab using add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to dynamically change the style of a tab using the add-on SDK. How can I do this?

Here's what I have tried:

I can access tab objects like this:

```
var tabs=require('sdk/tabs');
tabs.on('ready',function(tab){
  console.log('url is: '+tab.url); //-> url is http://www.google.com
  console.log('stlye is: '+tab.url); //-> style is null
});
```

But the style attribute is `null` and none of the following work:

```
tab.setAttribute('style','background-color:blue'); // the method doesn't exist
tab.style.backgroundColor='blue'; // type error because style is null
tab.style='background-color:blue'; // has no effect
```

So how can I change the style of a tab dynamically? Another thing I have tried is converting the tab to a XUL object using [code from the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs):

```
var { modelFor } = require("sdk/model/core");
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");

var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var tab_utils = require("sdk/tabs/utils");

function mapHighLevelToLowLevel(tab) {
  // get the XUL tab that corresponds to this high-level tab
  var lowLevelTab = viewFor(tab);
  // now we can, for example, access the tab's content directly
  var browser = tab_utils.getBrowserForTab(lowLevelTab);
  console.log(browser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
  // get the high-level tab back from the XUL tab
  var highLevelTab = modelFor(lowLevelTab);
  console.log(highLevelTab.url);
}

tabs.on("ready", mapHighLevelToLowLevel);
```

But the code throws an error: *Module 'sdk/model/core' is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/model/core.js*
even though I followed the directions and created the core.js file. Also, I don't understand the what the curly braces are doing in the `var { modelFor}=` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the xul tab element.

Try this:

```
var tabsLib = require("tabs/tab.js");
var tab = tabsLib.getTabForWindow(htmlWindow);
tab.style.color = 'red'; //makes the tab text red
```

pass `htmlWindow` as the topmost window of the html document. So like `document.defaultView.top`. `document.defaultView` is the `window` of the `document`

if that doesnt work then just get the browser window, this example gets the most recent browser window (keeep in mind there may be multiple browser windows open (browser window is a firefox window that has tabs, [and maybe popup windows- im not sure in sdk])

```
    const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
    var aDOMWindow = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser && aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
        var tabs = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
            for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
                tabs[i].style.color = 'red'; //makes the tab text red;
           }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help and will try your solution soon. Can you explain the `const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow} =` syntax? What do the curly braces do? Is it ES6 destructuring?

Comment: `const` is just a `var` that can't be changed after that line. Yep the curly and equals means, "find `getMostRecentBrowserWindow` in object of `require('sdk/window/utils')` and bring it to your scope, to your `const` or `var`". If there is no `getMostRecentWindow` in the object it wont work.

Comment: The second code block worked like a charm. The first didn't work because `htmlWindow` is undefined, but maybe I misunderstood. This is so great! Thank you.